# alterar propriedades de palavra na pesquisa php

Tags: php, css

fala pessoal, é o seguinte eu tenho um script de pesquisa com php, eu gostaria de quando ele exibisse o resultado as propriedades da palavra pesquisada fossem alteradas(background, tamanho, etc), por exemplo eu pesquiso o nome de usuario 'joao' o sistema me retorna  uma tabela com os resultados referentes só que invés de me mostrar o resultado normal  o sistema alteraria o background da palavra que foi pesquisada, bom o problema é o seguinte eu não sei se consigo, ou devo fazer isso só com php, ou devo utilizar javascript, lembrando que não estou pedindo nenhum código pronto e sim o "melhor caminho"

segue o código de como os resultados da consulta são exibidos

```
while ($linha = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                                        echo '<tr class="odd gradeX">';
                                        echo '<td>' . $linha['NOME'] . '</td>';
                                        echo '<td>' . $linha['EMAIL'] . '</td>';
                                        echo '<td>' . $linha['LOGIN'] . '</td>';
                                        echo '<td>' . $linha['DT_NASCIMENTO'] . '</td>';
                                        echo '<td>' . $linha['DT_ULTIMOACESSO'] . '</td>';
                                        echo '<td>' . $linha['IP'] . '</td>';
                                        echo '</td>';

                                    }
```

o código acima gera os resultados desta tabela 
[image: exemplo]

Comment: Sinceramente chará eu não consegui entender o que você quer dizer com `background`? Você quer destacar as palavras?

Comment: realmente acho que me expressei mal, e basicamente isso como acontece no duckduckgo.com quando você pesquisa sobre algo ele deixa em **negrito** o termo

Comment: Qual variável é recebida pela "querie" do PDO? Forneça um código mais completo, não tem como saber o que é necessário modificar. Leia isto *por favor*: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Guilherme uma imagem em nada ajuda, pois o problema não é entender **o que você quer**, mas sim tentar **entender o que você já fez**, pois você só colocou um pedaço de código. Veja se a minha resposta lhe ajuda

Comment: Boa tarde, minha resposta lhe ajudou? Por favor me informe se tiver alguma duvida ainda. se não e a resposta lhe foi útil, por favor marque a como "correta". Grato.

Comment: opa @GuilhermeNascimento desculpa pela demora em marcar como correta havia esquecido, obrigado pela ajuda chara

Comment: Que bom que pude ajudar, desejo sucesso a você e aos seus projetos chara. +1 pra ti

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supondo que você utilize uma query assim `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE NOME LIKE ? OR EMAIL LIKE ?` e uma variável dentro da global chamada `$_GET`, o melhor caminho seria criar uma *função* para fazer o efeito combinado ao CSS, seria algo como:

```
function highlightResult($str, $keyword) {
    return str_replace($keyword, '<strong class="destaque">' . $keyword . '</strong>', $str);
}
```

O `str_replace` busca todas os locais com a palavras consultada dentro da `string` e adiciona a tag `<strong class="destaque">`, assim poderemos aplicar um efeito usando CSS

Segue um exemplo de uso:

```
<?php
function highlightResult($str, $keyword) {
    return str_replace($keyword, '<strong class="destaque">' . $keyword . '</strong>');
}

if (isset($_GET['consulta'])) {//Presumindo que o nome da variável seja consulta
    $consulta = $_GET['consulta'];
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('
        SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE NOME LIKE ? OR EMAIL LIKE ?
    ');
    $busca = array('%' . $consulta . '%', '%' . $consulta . '%');
    $sth->execute($busca);

    while ($linha = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<tr class="odd gradeX">';
        echo '<td>',  highlightResult($linha['NOME'], $consulta), '</td>'; //Adiciona efeito de destaque na primeira coluna
        echo '<td>',  highlightResult($linha['EMAIL'], $consulta) '</td>'; //Adiciona efeito de destaque na segunda coluna
        echo '<td>',  $linha['LOGIN'], '</td>';
        echo '<td>',  $linha['DT_NASCIMENTO'], '</td>';
        echo '<td>',  $linha['DT_ULTIMOACESSO'], '</td>';
        echo '<td>',  $linha['IP'], '</td>';
        echo '</td>';
    }
} else {
    ...
}
```

O CSS deve ser algo como (modifique conforme a sua necessidade):

```
strong.destaque {/*Strong já possui um efeito parecido com o negrito*/
   color: red; /*modifique a cor conforme necessário*/
}
```